# Send Json to wcf from Android

Tags: android, json, wcf

I creating a wcf service in vb.net. The service code is here:

```
 <ServiceContract()>
 Public Interface IServiceUpload
  <OperationContract()> _
  <WebInvoke(Method:="POST", BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json,UriTemplate:="UploadFile")>
    Function UploadFile(F As FileStructure) As String

<DataContract()> _
Class FileStructure

    <DataMember()> _
    Public Property gp1 As String
 End Class
End Interface
```

I send json data via Android from this code:

```
        JSONStringer UPJ = new JSONStringer();

        try {
            UPJ.object()
                        .key("F").object().key("gp1")
                        .value("50").endObject().endObject();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
   OutputStream outputStream = new  BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
          String upload=jsonObject2.toString();

            writer.write(UPJ.toString());
```

My problem is I always return http error 400 when trying to read F.gp1 in service. I think sent json is null. Help me plz!

Comment: HTTP 400 means "Bad Request": The server cannot or will not process the request due to an apparent client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, too large size, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing). So may be You miss "Content-Type" "application/json" in header or something like this? Can You actually sent JSON tou your wcf via web REST Client?

Comment: I will receive HTTP 200 if I don't want to get F properties.